# WLST get current sessions and connections weblogic

Tags: weblogic-10.x, wlst

i need a wlst script to get **current sessions** of a specific deployment and current connections of a managed server. weblogic version 10.3.6.0

Is there any wlst  command to search an attribute name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect('user','pass','t3://ip:port')

serverRuntime()

get('/ApplicationRuntimes/application name/ComponentRuntimes/managed servername/application name/OpenSessionsCurrentCount')

get('/ServerChannelRuntimes/Default[http]/ConnectionsCount')

disconnect()